# MySql and PHP - Fetch next row in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query which selects scan details from the database. Those details are placed in a report. It was requested to have the reports displaying in two columns (almost two tables) on one page, to preserve the space that it takes.

What I am currently doing is displaying the table header:

```
 $report .= ">
                    <table cellspacing='0' class='at_report'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr><th colspan='8'>Area ".$row['area_name']."</th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:7%;'><div class='nosplit'>No.</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:8%;'><div class='nosplit'>Barcode</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:40%;'><div class='nosplit'>Product</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:5%;'><div class='nosplit'>Qty</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:7%;'><div class='nosplit'>Cost Value</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:16%;'><div class='nosplit'>Created By</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:10%;'><div class='nosplit'>Time</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:7%;'><div class='nosplit'>No.</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:8%;'><div class='nosplit'>Barcode</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:40%;'><div class='nosplit'>Product</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:5%;'><div class='nosplit'>Qty</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:7%;'><div class='nosplit'>Cost Value</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:16%;'><div class='nosplit'>Created By</div></td>
                            <td class='simple_header' style='width:10%;'><div class='nosplit'>Time</div></td>
                        </tr>
                         ";
```

Then I fetch the results from the database:

```
 while ($srow = $scan_res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Then I display the results in the table:

```
 $report .= "<tr ".$row_style.">
                                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$n."</div></td>
                                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$srow['barcode']."</div></td>
                                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$product_nd_short."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$rounded_qty."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$cur_symbol.$cn.$mcost_estimated."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".((strlen($srow['stocktake_staff_name'])>16)? substr($srow['stocktake_staff_name'], 0, 16)."..." : $srow['stocktake_staff_name'])."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$dt->format('H:i:s')."</div></td></tr>";
```

My question is, how do I go to the next set of results in the while loop, so that I can add another column with set of results in the table? I tried this:

```
$report .= "<tr ".$row_style.">
                                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$n."</div></td>
                                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$srow['barcode']."</div></td>
                                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$product_nd_short."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$rounded_qty."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$cur_symbol.$cn.$mcost_estimated."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".((strlen($srow['stocktake_staff_name'])>16)? substr($srow['stocktake_staff_name'], 0, 16)."..." : $srow['stocktake_staff_name'])."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$dt->format('H:i:s')."</div></td>";       
                $row_counter++;     
                $n++;
                   $report .= "
                                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$n."</div> </td>
                                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$srow['barcode']."</div></td>
                                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$product_nd_short."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$rounded_qty."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$cur_symbol.$cn.$mcost_estimated."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".((strlen($srow['stocktake_staff_name'])>16)? substr($srow['stocktake_staff_name'], 0, 16)."..." : $srow['stocktake_staff_name'])."</div></td>
                                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$dt->format('H:i:s')."</div></td> 
                            </tr>";
```

But all it does is duplicating the result from the first set.

Thanks!

Comment: There's documentation on php.net And it is all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need something like this.

You want to place the 2 result in a same row.

```
$n = 1;
while($srow = $scan_res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($n % 2 != 0)
        $report .= "<tr ".$row_style.">";

    $report .= "<td><div class='nosplit'>".$n."</div></td>
              <td><div class='nosplit'>".$srow['barcode']."</div></td>
              <td><div class='nosplit'>".$product_nd_short."</div></td>
              <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$rounded_qty."</div></td>
              <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$cur_symbol.$cn.$mcost_estimated."</div></td>
              <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".((strlen($srow['stocktake_staff_name'])>16)? substr($srow['stocktake_staff_name'], 0, 16)."..." : $srow['stocktake_staff_name'])."</div></td>
              <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$dt->format('H:i:s')."</div></td>";
    if($n % 2 == 0)
        $report .= "</tr>";
    $n++;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you! Is it possible to go 
1 | 4
2 | 5
3 | 6 as the results? What would I need to do to achieve that?

Comment: Possible, then you need to carry the result in an array and arrange the array you need.

Comment: I was asked to change the sorting of results to 1 | 4 2 | 5 3 | 6 etc.
I have the results of MySQL query in an array. What is the correct approach? This is what I have tried
http://pastebin.com/RAxkA1zh

Comment: I forgot what i did, why i did. let me check. what are these `1 | 4 2 | 5 3 | 6`

Comment: Basically I need all results to show in the left column of the table until it reaches half way, then show the rest of the results on the right. <br/>
Result 1 | Result 4 <br/>
Result 2 | Result 5 <br/>
Result 3 | Result 6

Answer (score 0):

Ehm,

its a bit confusing your question, but i think i know what you mean....

```
while ($srow = $scan_res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $n++;
    $report .= "<tr><td><div class='nosplit'>".$n."</div></td>
                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$srow['barcode']."</div></td>
                <td><div class='nosplit'>".$product_nd_short."</div></td>
                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$rounded_qty."</div></td>
                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$cur_symbol.$cn.$mcost_estimated."</div></td>
                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".((strlen($srow['stocktake_staff_name'])>16)? substr($srow['stocktake_staff_name'], 0, 16)."..." : $srow['stocktake_staff_name'])."</div></td>
                <td style='text-align:center;'><div class='nosplit'>".$dt->format('H:i:s')."</div></td></tr>";
}
```

i haven't tried running it ... but it should do what you want.

- make sure you have the statements you want to repeat inside the curly braces {}  after your while statement
- make sure to start row with  and end it with
- you only use barcode and stock_staff_name variables from your data rows ... other values you seem to have pre set ... so those will always be the same ($rounded_qty, $dt, $product_nd_short .... so if you would like this to be from your row ... then read them from your row in your while statement.

Comment: Yea, that only fetches one row of results and puts it in one column. I want to have the table divided in a way
[dataset1] | [dataset2]
where "|" is page middle. I can get results for dataset1, but I can't seem to get php to go to the next result in the while loop for dataset2

Comment: This block will make two result in a single row. But the OP needs to taking two result in a single row.